# Could colored glass used in beverage bottles also work as laser glass?

Tags: laser

I've been reading about nif (specifically here: https://lasers.llnl.gov/about/how-nif-works/beamline/amplifiers )
 and I saw the part about the laser glass amplifiers and I have a green Heineken bottle right here, and I thought hey, that's pretty similar. They are both glass, doped with some kind of metal to change the colors..

Comment: There's an old saw that anything will lase if you pump it hard enough. There's even been a "pickle laser" using a pickled cucumber as the gain medium.

Comment: @ThePhoton this sounds interesting, any links?

Answer (score 0):

From your link:

> The glass slabs are “doped” with neodymium atoms, which impart a pinkish color to the glass.
>
> When the slabs are bathed in the intense white light of the flashlamps that surround them, the neodymium atoms are raised to higher energy states (see How Lasers Work). When a low-energy laser pulse from the injection laser system passes through the slabs, the neodymium atoms release their extra energy into the laser pulse in the form of photons, increasing the pulse’s brightness. The neodymium-doped phosphate laser glass is the result of a six-year joint research and development program with industrial partners SCHOTT North America and Hoya Corp. USA. This effort developed a revolutionary process for manufacturing meter-size slabs of laser glass that is 10 times faster, five times cheaper, and with better optical quality .

1) the color is incidental to the neodymium doping

2) I am sure Heineken is not using neodyium doped white glass ( which in any case would not be green)

3) you need slabs to create a coherent laser beam from the process

So the answer is no.

Comment: Just because Heineken isn't using Nd glass doesn't mean the colorant they use (iron oxide?) doesn't have some levels that can be used to make a laser.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Did you glance at the link? They took a lot of trouble to get where they are.  Would one go to such trouble for a beer bottle? The color is incidental to the doping,  (and it was not green)  which is intentional and needed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_amplifier#Doped_fibre_amplifiers_for_other_wavelength_ranges

Comment: Yes, but OP didn't specify they want an efficient laser, or a high power laser, or a specific pulse power. All that engineering at NIF wasn't to demonstrate the first Nd:glass laser, it was to get megajoule pulses without blowing it up. I've never heard of an Fe:glass laser, so it's likely not easy to get that Heineken bottle to lase. But I think it takes more than "it took a lot of work to make the NIF laser" to prove the Heineken bottle can't lase at all.

Comment: The wording on my question is ambiguous. I was more wondering if it could be used at all in any laser, but the wording, "also work as laser glass" could be interpreted to mean "could it replace that glass at nif." Which I agree is unlikely.